# sorting cell array based on column (double not char) values

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, cell

I have a 3x1 cell array A which includes:

```
10.2  
15.2  
7.2
```

and another 3x1 cell Array B includes:

```
m
l
s
```

I would like to join these into a new 3x2 cell Array C including:

```
10.2  m
15.2  l
7.2   v
```

then I want to sort C according to the values of the first column which is supposed to be

```
7.2 v
10.2 m
15.2 l
```

what I did so far to do this is as follows:

```
C=A;
C(:,2)=B;
C=sortrows(C,1);
```

However the result is:

```
10.2 m
15.2 l
7.2 v
```

I think the reason is that it considers the numbers in the first column as characters and the way it sorts them is by looking at the digits of each number one by one from the left.. thus 10.2 is less than 7.2.
I am looking for a way to assign the numbers as numbers to C so when I sort them it considers them as numbers not characters.  I tried to use cell2mat when assigning A and B to C but did not work.  I have searched the web for this but could not find what I am looking for.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would do what you need:

```
>>
C = cell(numel(A),2);
[Sorted_A, Index_A] = sort(cell2mat(A));
C(:,1) = num2cell(Sorted_A);
C(:,2) = B(Index_A);
```

For example, for the input as follows:

```
>>
A = {10.2; 15.2; 7.2};
B = {'m'; 'l'; 'v'};
```

The result would be:

```
>> C

C = 

    [ 7.2000]    'v'
    [10.2000]    'm'
    [15.2000]    'l'
```

### EDIT

It seems that in your case, the input array `A` is not just a cell array of numbers, but a cell array of strings; i.e., for example,

```
>>
A = {'10.2'; '15.2'; '7.2'};
```

In this case, you need to make the following changes:

1. Use `str2double(A)` instead of `cell2mat(A)`
2. Use `strtrim(cellstr(num2str(Sorted_A)))` instead of `num2cell(Sorted_A);`

Your final code will now be:

```
>>
C = cell(numel(A),2);
[Sorted_A, Index_A] = sort(str2double(A));
C(:,1) = strtrim(cellstr(num2str(Sorted_A)));
C(:,2) = B(Index_A);
```

For example, for the input as follows:

```
>>
A = {'10.2'; '15.2'; '7.2'};
B = {'m'; 'l'; 'v'};
```

The result would be:

```
>> C

C = 

    '7.2'     'v'
    '10.2'    'm'
    '15.2'    'l'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I still have a problem.  A is 3x1 cell array where each cell is 1x(number_of_digits) char.  So cell2mat is causing error if numbers have different number of digits e.x. 0.2 and 0.03 both present in the array I get the error: CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.  

Error in cell2mat (line 84)
            m{n} = cat(1,c{:,n});

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way: use the second output from `sort`:

```
% your data
a = {
    '10.2' 
    '15.2' 
    '7.2'
};

b = {
    'm'
    'l'
    's'
};

c = [a b];


% sort the first column, and save the indices    
[~,I] = sort(str2double(c(:,1)))

% use the indices to sort the concatenation c:
c(I,:)
```

Comment: It did not work.  a{:} returns whole a not the first column.  Thanks though